# Taylor expansion of a matrix with multiple variable

Tags: taylor-expansion, calculus-of-variations, matrix-exponential

$$
G(x,y,t)=e^{- x \pmatrix{1&0 \\0&-1} - y \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} - t\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0} }
$$

where $x,y,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to Taylor expand G around an infinetisimal change of x,y,t.

---

In the unitary case:

$$
U(t)=e^{-itH}
$$

the result is

$$
U(\delta t) = 1- i\delta t H
$$

---

But, how to I calculate it for multiple variables simultaneously?

What is $G(\delta x, \delta y, \delta t)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call

$$
Z = -x \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\0 & -1} - y \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\1 & 0} - t \pmatrix{0 & -1 \\1 & 0}
$$

so your problem becomes

$$
e^Z = 1 + Z + \frac{Z^2}{2} + \cdots
$$

if you want to keep up to linear terms (like in your example) then

$$
G\approx 1 + Z = 1 -\delta x \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\0 & -1} - \delta y \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\1 & 0} - \delta t \pmatrix{0 & -1 \\1 & 0}
$$